# Visibility of CSS doesn't work on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      function show() { 
        document.getElementById("dd").style.visibility = "visible"; 
        document.getElementById("dd").style.position = "relative"; 
      } 
    </script> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <div style="width:30%; float:left"> 
      <div class="nav" style=" background-color:Red"> <a href="home.html"> Home</a>
      </div> 
      <div class="nav" style=" background-color:Red"><a href="abt.html"> About US</a>
      </div> 
      <div class="nav" style=" background-color:Red"><a href="client.html"> Client</a>
      </div>        
      <div class="nav" style=" background-color:Red"><a href="cont.html"> Contact</a>   
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div style="width:70%; float:left; "> 
      <a href="#" onclick="show()">dropdown</a> 
      <div style="position:absolute; visibility:hidden" id="dd">
        We, We carry out erection, testing, commissioning and maintenance services             
        We have an excellent reputation, a quality work ethic and a team of qualified and        
        highly experienced workforce.
      </div>      
    </div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

The idea is to click the `dropdown` link and the `div#dd` will be visible. It works on PC browsers, but it doesn't work on mobile. Although, other JavaScripts (like `window.alert`) works.

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: What mobile OS are you using? You might want to try the following: `<a href="javascript:show();">dropdown</a> `

Comment: @merlin: still doesn't work

Comment: what OS are you using? I do not know what the problem is, but this information but might lead others to the solution

Comment: its a java based phone with no OS

Comment: no OS? and what browser are you using? Are you sure your phone fully supports javascript and html?

Comment: yes, other javascript functions and html are working

Comment: What happens after the execution of the `show()` function? What action does the browser take when the user clicks on the link?

Comment: the broswer just refreshes and the div#dd is not visible...apparently  nothing happens

Comment: Does the browser _need_ to refresh?